# Envoy ratelimit based on request body

Tags: rate-limiting, envoyproxy

I want to limit request taken by Envoyproxy based on the request bodies. For example I want to send the `md5('%REQ_BODY%')` to rate-limit service as a descriptor value.

My current envoy yaml config is here:

```yaml
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/api/v1/sms" }
                          route: 
                            cluster: sms
                            rate_limits:
                            - actions:
                              - generic_key:
                                  descriptor_value: "{{ md5('%REQ_BODY%') }}"
                                  descriptor_key: body
```

Also I added the ratelimit filter to the http_filters section:

```yaml
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.ratelimit
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ratelimit.v3.RateLimit
                      domain: my_domain
                      enable_x_ratelimit_headers: DRAFT_VERSION_03
                      rate_limit_service:
                        transport_api_version: V3
                        grpc_service:
                          envoy_grpc:
                            cluster_name: rate-limit
```

But it seems the config sends the exact value of `"{{ md5('%REQ_BODY%') }}"` to the service and doesn't interpret it.

Here is rate limit service configuration file:

```yaml
domain: my_domain
descriptors:
  - key: body
    rate_limit:
      unit: minute
      requests_per_unit: 1
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution.

I added the filter in `http_filters` section:

```yaml
- name: envoy.filters.http.lua
typed_config:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
  inline_code: |
    function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
      local body = request_handle:body()
      local jsonString = tostring(body:getBytes(0, body:length()))
      request_handle:headers():add("x-body", jsonString)
    end
```

And then I added the following action to rate_limits section of the route:

```yaml
routes:
  - match: { prefix: "/api/v1/sms" }
  route: 
    cluster: sms
    rate_limits:
      - actions:
        - request_headers:
          header_name: x-body
          descriptor_key: body
```